# Tor file descriptor usage at 100%

Tags: relays, directory, middle

I am running a non-exit Tor relay for the last few weeks and it is working but it is not maxing the Internet pipe. (The server is >2 weeks old, so not a problem of age)

The problem is that it seems that Tor's file descriptor usage are at 100%. Nyx shows this:

file descriptors: 4074 / 4064 (100%)

I am running the server on an unprivileged LXC container and it just works fine but this is what is bugging me out. Is that number of file descriptors acceptable, or should I raise it? How does it get filled? Doesn't it get (recycled?) at certain times?

I have enough RAM and CPU as they are idling at 15% usage. By the way, I am running a directory. Don't know if that affects to file descriptors usage.

I haven't been able to find any answer to this matter. Hope you can help me.

Comment: do you have a static or dynamic IP from your ISP? - i'm not sure if it applies to your case, but i read somewhere, that dynamic IPs are not that good for relays... if this is the case, providing a bridge is a better way of contributing. **--** BUT again: **it's just a shot in the dark!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Tor manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ConnLimit) states:

> Tor will ask the OS for as many file descriptors as the OS will allow (you can find this by "ulimit -H -n"). If this number is less than ConnLimit, then Tor will refuse to start.

This number appears to be the denominator of the fraction you see in Nyx (4064). It's returned [from tor](https://github.com/torproject/tor/blob/7fbfdf2af731f500e3df3ca8207e6822f87f1bc9/src/feature/control/control.c#L1961) to Stem by the `process/descriptor-limit` control message.

The number of in-use file descriptors (4074) comes [directly from Stem](https://stem.torproject.org/_modules/stem/util/proc.html#file_descriptors_used), which simply counts the number of items in `/proc/$pid/fd`.

```
return len(os.listdir('/proc/%i/fd' % pid))
```

The Tor source code also has a [tuning document](https://github.com/torproject/tor/blob/master/doc/TUNING) that describes how to increase the number of available file descriptors if you are running low.

> Most operating systems limit an amount of TCP sockets that can be used 
>   simultaneously. It is possible for a busy Tor relay to run into these
>   limits, thus being unable to fully utilize the bandwidth resources it 
>   has at its disposal. Following system-specific tips might be helpful
>   to alleviate the aforementioned problem.
>
> **Linux**
>
> Use 'ulimit -n' to raise an allowed number of file descriptors to be 
>   opened on your host at the same time.

The [Nyx source code](https://gitweb.torproject.org/nyx.git/tree/nyx/panel/header.py#n199) shows that it logs a warning message if the file descriptor usage is above 90%. You should check for this message.

```
log_msg = "Tor's file descriptor usage is at %s%%. If you run out Tor will be unable to continue functioning." % fd_percent
log.log_once('fd_used_at_ninety_percent', log.WARN, log_msg)
```

It would probably be a good idea to raise the limit in the kernel and see what happens. I wouldn't be sure that you'll get much more traffic, as some Tor relays aren't getting the max bandwidth that they specify in their torrc.